# Wordpress asking for FTP details when installing plugins

Tags: authentication, ftp

I'm renting a server from [DigitalOcean](http://digitalocean.com/) on which I'm running Wordpress inside apache on port 8079. DigitalOcean also only allows one to connect via SFTP. Currently the client I use to do that is [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/) . My details for that is like follow:

[image]

So since my apache instance is running on port 8079, does that mean that when Wordpress asks for my FTP details that it'll look something like this?:

[image]

Because it's not working. My Wordpress installation on my server is under `/var/www/previews/sample/`

Answer (score 1):

The port of Apache web server is only used for HTTP protocol, that is actually serving web pages. It is different from file transfer protocols and Apache itself actually doesn't implement those functions, they are handled by their own server software.

If SFTP port isn't default, you should look up in the documentation or contact support about what connection details precisely should you provide to WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that Digital Ocean do not care much if you use FTP or SFTP, but SFTP is a file transfer protocol over SSH and therefor enabled whenever SSH is enabled, and SSH is the only way to manage your server.

If you want to use FTP for file transfer then you will need to install an FTP server. I advice against it as by definition FTP is less secure then SFTP (passwords are sent as clear text), this will cost you the ability to do updates from the wordpress admin, but in the long run it is a very small price to pay.

Comment: Agreed: Remove the port number from the Hostname in the plugin's configuration.